# Write a 2-D matrix based on the sum of some 2-D basis

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, change-of-basis

I have a 2-D matrix ($P \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$) and I have $N$ basis with size $N\times N$ called $B_i$. I want to write $P$ based on a weighted sum of $B_i$s as follow:

$P = \sum_i c_i B_i$

I know that every $B_i = u_iu_i^T$ where every $u_i$ is the eigenvector of another matrix called $Q$. I can write $Q = \sum_i \lambda_i B_i$ where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue of $Q$, but how can I find $c_i$s to write $P$ as sum of basis?

Comment: I think you need to double-index your basis matrices $B$ to write them as products of eigenvectors $u u^T$. Specifically, if you have basis $(B_{i,j})_{1 \le i, j \le N}$, then you can write $B_{i,j} = u_i u_j^T$. Also, if I'm understanding your question correctly, you can drop all instances of "2-D", as that is implicitly given for most users of the site.

Comment: @Jackson Yes Yes, thanks for your comment, I totally forgot that we need $N\times N$ basis and $B_{i,j}$s are basis not just $B_i$s. I think I got my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Jackson Do you have any intuition behind the outer product of two eigenvector? What does every basis show?

Comment: If you in a new stack exchange question, I'll try to give a good answer. And I probably won't be the only one to respond

Comment: Sorry, my comment above is missing the word "ask." If you ask in a new question, I'll answer. I don't understand why I can't edit my comment?

Comment: @Jackson Thanks for your reply. Here is my question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783468/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-outer-product-of-two-eigenvectors